# What causes the "ripples" that extend east-west along the mid-atlantic ridge?

Tags: topography, ocean-ridge

Below are two cropped screenshots from the super-cool video [Draining Earth's oceans, revealing the two-thirds of Earth's surface we don't get to see](https://youtu.be/-uOwv_Krqk8) with the oceans "drained" to 4000 and 5000 meters below sea level.

We've all read about the magnetic field reversals leaving alternating lines of residual magnetic field trapped in the crust that go in the north-south direction, but I was surprised to see these topographic ripples that extend in the east-west direction.

What caused these to form?

I've added some annotation to indicate the direction of the ripples I think I'm seeing.

[image: cropped screen shots from Draining Earth's oceans, revealing the two-thirds of Earth's surface we don't get to see]

Comment: ["An oceanic core complex, or megamullion, is a seabed geologic feature that forms a long ridge perpendicular to a mid-ocean ridge. It contains smooth domes that are lined with transverse ridges like a corrugated roof. They can vary in size from 10 to 150 km in length, 5 to 15 km in width, and 500 to 1500 m in height."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oceanic_core_complex) [Role of melt supply in oceanic detachment faulting and formation of megamullions](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/73dc/11f7a8c2d8a0e177af5e2dab38b811b5920a.pdf?_ga=2.108718274.1341586451.1580794274-721078197.1580506373)

Comment: @KeithMcClary searching for "megamillions" finds this http://rjes.wdcb.ru/v06/tje04146/fig01.htm which contains https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wMN7.gif Any chance you're interested in writing this up as a short answer?

Comment: 1 hour 2015 lecture: ["The Life and Death of Oceanic Core Complexes and the Largest Normal Faults in the World."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGDqbasw19I) about how this is more complicated than previously thought.

Comment: @KeithMcClary cool! *I love stuff* that turns out to be "...more complicated than previously thought!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are transform faults that result from differential spreading rates of the middle ocean ridge. As such they are part of the plate boundary. Possible causes are different production rates of magma, thermal differences of the sea floor, differences of relative plate movement.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transform_fault

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-ocean_ridge

Paywalled:
[Dynamical Instability Produces Transform Faults at Mid-Ocean Ridges](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/329/5995/1047.full)

And:
Wilson, 1965: [A New Class of Faults and their Bearing on Continental Drift](https://www.nature.com/articles/207343a0)

Inactive transform faults extending beyond the spreading zone are sometimes generally named "fracture zone".

But transform faults can also reach all the way to the next subduction zone (e.g. Azores-Gibraltar fault zone) and be responsible for devastating [earthquakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1755_Lisbon_earthquake).

Comment: Thanks! It's great when a new user stops by and immediately starts solving puzzles.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to find something more sciency than the wikipedia links but it appears to be mostly paywalled or from a past millennium. The articles seem to be quite reasonable, on first site :-)

Comment: Okay I'll give them a read through in the morning and check the paywalled one when I get to the library.

Comment: And virtually ANY geology text book, high school and above, created in the last 50 years would also solve this "puzzle".

Comment: True, but for that, the question lingered too long without an answer. A textbook has it, but finding a non-paywalled recent paper wasn't easy (or I'm too quick). But it sure has a few funny remarks up there ("megamillions") :-)

Comment: Also, it's hard to for a spreading center to keep to a straight line on a round Earth, and the rock tends to fracture in a rectangular fashion.

Comment: If i recall it right there can be a connection between the Euler points of plate motion and the orientation of the transform cracks at a constructive boundary (angular motion, distance from rotation pole, and all that). But i leave that for someone else to find out and describe properly ...

Comment: Thank you for the reminder! I've just downloaded "Dynamical Instability..." (some problem getting the 1965 Nature paper but I really look forward to reading it!) and will read ASAP! As a side note, I sometimes wait a week or longer before accepting an answer. This has several benefits including there being more incentive for additional answers to be posted and when one is accepted it bumps the question back to the active queue which often results in more people having a look and up voting the excellent answers.

Comment: I couldn't see this linger for another month :-) On to what's up next !

Comment: [Dynamical Instability Produces Transform Faults at Mid-Ocean Ridges](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40803011?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) non-paywalled.